# Google Cloud - Sys Err 28 - No space left after rebooting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm not an expert on servers, but I had to reboot an instance on Google Cloud Platform, and after that I got an Error n 28. I was able to connect through serial port, tried to create a new instance with the snapshot I took of that disk, whatsoever the error persists. As not-a-expert I have no clue on how to solve that problem. If you had any tips I'll be very grateful.

```
Welcome to [1mUbuntu 18.04.3 LTS[0m!
[    7.197152] cloud-init[733]: tee: /var/log/cloud-init-output.log: No space left on device
[    7.198408] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,138 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/log/cloud-init.log - ab: [644] 0 bytes
[    7.199329] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,139 - util.py[DEBUG]: Changing the ownership of /var/log/cloud-init.log to 102:4
[    7.199740] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,139 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished
[    7.199960] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,139 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/data/no-net
[    7.200188] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,140 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [check]
[    7.200392] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,140 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
[    7.200651] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,140 - stages.py[DEBUG]: no cache found
[    7.200890] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,140 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/check-cache: SUCCESS: no cache found
[    7.201099] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,140 - util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to remove /var/lib/cloud/instance
[    7.204812] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,144 - stages.py[DEBUG]: Using distro class <class 'cloudinit.distros.ubuntu.Distro'>
[    7.205187] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,145 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Looking for data source in: ['GCE', 'None'], via packages ['', 'cloudinit.sources'] that matches dependencies ['FILESYSTEM']
[    7.210174] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,150 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Searching for local data source in: []
[    7.210438] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,150 - main.py[DEBUG]: No local datasource found
[    7.211235] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,151 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/name_assign_type (quiet=False)
[    7.211457] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,151 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/name_assign_type
[    7.211700] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,151 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/carrier (quiet=False)
[    7.211919] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/dormant (quiet=False)
[    7.212122] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/operstate (quiet=False)
[    7.212337] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/operstate
[    7.212595] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/address (quiet=False)
[    7.212807] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/address
[    7.213032] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/address (quiet=False)
[    7.213239] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/address
[    7.213440] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,152 - stages.py[DEBUG]: applying net config names for {'config': [{'type': 'physical', 'name': 'ens4', 'mac_address': '42:01:0a:9e:00:11', 'subnets': [{'type': 'dhcp'}]}], 'version': 1}
[    7.213647] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/device/device (quiet=False)
[    7.213857] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 7 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/device/device
[    7.214072] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/addr_assign_type (quiet=False)
[    7.214280] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/addr_assign_type
[    7.214484] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/uevent (quiet=False)
[    7.214688] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 25 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/uevent
[    7.214889] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/address (quiet=False)
[    7.215092] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,153 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/address
[    7.215300] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/device/device (quiet=False)
[    7.269476] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 7 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/device/device
[    7.269647] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/addr_assign_type (quiet=False)
[    7.269831] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 2 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/addr_assign_type
[    7.269938] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/uevent (quiet=False)
[    7.270078] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 23 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/uevent
[    7.270176] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/address (quiet=False)
[    7.270284] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/address
[    7.270379] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,154 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/device/device (quiet=False)
[    7.270534] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,155 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/ens4/operstate (quiet=False)
[    7.270629] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,155 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 5 bytes from /sys/class/net/ens4/operstate
[    7.270761] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,155 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /sys/class/net/lo/operstate (quiet=False)
[    7.270857] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,155 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 8 bytes from /sys/class/net/lo/operstate
[    7.270965] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,155 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['ip', '-6', 'addr', 'show', 'permanent', 'scope', 'global'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[    7.271061] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,171 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['ip', '-4', 'addr', 'show'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[    7.271232] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,175 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: no work necessary for renaming of [['42:01:0a:9e:00:11', 'ens4', 'virtio_net', '0x0001']]
[    7.271326] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,176 - stages.py[INFO]: Applying network configuration from fallback bringup=False: {'config': [{'type': 'physical', 'name': 'ens4', 'mac_address': '42:01:0a:9e:00:11', 'subnets': [{'type': 'dhcp'}]}], 'version': 1}
[    7.271423] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,178 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/os-release (quiet=False)
[    7.271521] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,178 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 386 bytes from /etc/os-release
[    7.271643] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,180 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Selected renderer 'netplan' from priority list: None
[    7.271749] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,183 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - wb: [644] 473 bytes
[    7.271861] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,198 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['netplan', 'generate'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[    7.412225] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,351 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['udevadm', 'test-builtin', 'net_setup_link', '/sys/class/net/ens4'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[    7.418983] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,358 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['udevadm', 'test-builtin', 'net_setup_link', '/sys/class/net/lo'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
[    7.424030] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,363 - main.py[DEBUG]: [local] Exiting without datasource
[    7.424945] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,365 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
[    7.425214] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,365 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 11 bytes from /proc/uptime
[    7.425425] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,365 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'init' took 0.272 seconds (0.27)
[    7.425634] cloud-init[733]: FALLBACK: 2019-11-04 21:29:53,365 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local: FAIL: searching for local datasources
[    7.551545] cloud-init[733]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[    7.552317] cloud-init[733]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[    7.552755] cloud-init[733]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[    7.553087] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[    7.553196] cloud-init[733]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==19.1', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[    7.553404] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 893, in main
[    7.553611] cloud-init[733]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[    7.553820] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2521, in log_time
[    7.554026] cloud-init[733]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[    7.554322] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 671, in status_wrapper
[    7.554661] cloud-init[733]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[    7.554863] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[    7.554963] cloud-init[733]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[    7.555166] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[    7.555375] cloud-init[733]:     raise e
[    7.555595] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[    7.555800] cloud-init[733]:     tf.close()
[    7.555999] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[    7.556204] cloud-init[733]:     self._closer.close()
[    7.556527] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[    7.556746] cloud-init[733]:     self.file.close()
[    7.556947] cloud-init[733]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[    7.557156] cloud-init[733]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[    7.557255] cloud-init[733]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[    7.557452] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 109, in apport_excepthook
[    7.557661] cloud-init[733]:     pr.add_proc_info(extraenv=['PYTHONPATH', 'PYTHONHOME'])
[    7.557763] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 543, in add_proc_info
[    7.558175] cloud-init[733]:     self.add_proc_environ(pid, extraenv)
[    7.558410] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 610, in add_proc_environ
[    7.558646] cloud-init[733]:     env = _read_file('environ', dir_fd=proc_pid_fd).replace('\n', '\\n')
[    7.558848] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in _read_file
[    7.559049] cloud-init[733]:     with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
[    7.559287] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in <lambda>
[    7.559541] cloud-init[733]:     with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
[    7.559752] cloud-init[733]: TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not list
[    7.559963] cloud-init[733]: Original exception was:
[    7.560163] cloud-init[733]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[    7.560262] cloud-init[733]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[    7.560487] cloud-init[733]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[    7.560827] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[    7.560928] cloud-init[733]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==19.1', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[    7.561131] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 893, in main
[    7.561334] cloud-init[733]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[    7.561543] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2521, in log_time
[    7.561755] cloud-init[733]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[    7.561954] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 671, in status_wrapper
[    7.562176] cloud-init[733]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[    7.562380] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[    7.562479] cloud-init[733]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[    7.562692] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[    7.562892] cloud-init[733]:     raise e
[    7.563101] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[    7.563333] cloud-init[733]:     tf.close()
[    7.563433] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[    7.619468] cloud-init[733]:     self._closer.close()
[    7.619989] cloud-init[733]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).
See 'systemctl status cloud-init-local.service' for details.
[    7.620281] cloud-init[733]:     self.file.close()
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
[    7.620913] cloud-init[733]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
         Starting Network Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
         Starting Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)...
[   10.049472] cloud-init[958]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   10.049843] cloud-init[958]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   10.050122] cloud-init[958]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   10.050339] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[   10.050495] cloud-init[958]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==19.1', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   10.050628] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 893, in main
[   10.050792] cloud-init[958]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   10.050927] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2521, in log_time
[   10.051058] cloud-init[958]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   10.051257] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 648, in status_wrapper
[   10.051362] cloud-init[958]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[   10.051466] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[   10.051600] cloud-init[958]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   10.051714] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   10.051854] cloud-init[958]:     raise e
[   10.051967] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[   10.052102] cloud-init[958]:     tf.close()
[   10.052217] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[   10.052364] cloud-init[958]:     self._closer.close()
[   10.052521] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[   10.052719] cloud-init[958]:     self.file.close()
[   10.052928] cloud-init[958]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   10.053169] cloud-init[958]: Error in sys.excepthook:
[   10.053406] cloud-init[958]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   10.053614] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 109, in apport_excepthook
[   10.053835] cloud-init[958]:     pr.add_proc_info(extraenv=['PYTHONPATH', 'PYTHONHOME'])
[   10.054069] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 543, in add_proc_info
[   10.054285] cloud-init[958]:     self.add_proc_environ(pid, extraenv)
[   10.054507] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 610, in add_proc_environ
[   10.054718] cloud-init[958]:     env = _read_file('environ', dir_fd=proc_pid_fd).replace('\n', '\\n')
[   10.054942] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in _read_file
[   10.055173] cloud-init[958]:     with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
[   10.055407] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in <lambda>
[   10.055760] cloud-init[958]:     with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
[   10.055928] cloud-init[958]: TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not list
[   10.056126] cloud-init[958]: Original exception was:
[   10.056371] cloud-init[958]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[   10.056617] cloud-init[958]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[   10.056799] cloud-init[958]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   10.057007] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 11, in <module>
[   10.057142] cloud-init[958]:     load_entry_point('cloud-init==19.1', 'console_scripts', 'cloud-init')()
[   10.057278] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 893, in main
[   10.057422] cloud-init[958]:     get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
[   10.057542] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 2521, in log_time
[   10.057732] cloud-init[958]:     ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
[   10.057867] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 648, in status_wrapper
[   10.058000] cloud-init[958]:     atomic_helper.write_json(status_path, status)
[   10.058201] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 40, in write_json
[   10.058338] cloud-init[958]:     omode="w", mode=mode)
[   10.058460] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 33, in write_file
[   10.058564] cloud-init[958]:     raise e
[   10.115887] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/atomic_helper.py", line 27, in write_file
[   10.116050] cloud-init[958]:     tf.close()
[   10.116152] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 650, in close
[   10.116334] cloud-init[958]:     self._closer.close()
[   10.116453] cloud-init[958]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 584, in close
[   10.116627] cloud-init[958]:     self.file.close()
[   10.116813] cloud-init[958]: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
See 'systemctl status cloud-init.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Cloud-config availability.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Starting Availability of block devices...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Availability of block devices.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved easily.

- Go to the Google Console -> Compute Engine -> Disks.
- Select the disk for the instance.
- Click the edit button and resize the disk to a larger number.
- Reboot the instance.

When the instance restarts, the file system on the disk will be resized automatically.

If you are curious about the details, I wrote an article on this topic:

[Google Cloud - Resize Root File System](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/)